# How to initiate the format of a line in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

For example,the declaration of a point :
my_point, = plt.plot([], [], 'bx', alpha=.5).But it comes to wrong,when i use the format like :
my_line, = plt.plot([,], [,], color='brown', linestyle='-')
or my_line, = plt.plot([[],[]], [[],[]], color='brown', linestyle='-').
Because i want to plot a line between two points with data stored in list. I want to get the right format.

```
my_point, = plt.plot([], [], 'bx', alpha=.5)
my_line, = plt.plot([,], [,], color='brown', linestyle='-')
```

Comment: By the method: my_point.set_data(,) , the point  can be plot, but the same way is likely wrong.

Comment: I genuinely don't understand, what your question is. Seemingly, [something the documentation does not cover.](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) I suggest providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: first thing it will give syntax error

Comment: Yeah,it truly gives syntax error,so i want to know the right format initiating a line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax `[,]` does not make any sense. You would instead initialize your line the same way as your point; this is because the plot function does not even know about it being a point or a line.

```
my_point, = plt.plot([], [], 'bx', alpha=.5)
my_line,  = plt.plot([], [], color='brown', linestyle='-')
```

Comment: This is actually what i mean.Thank you very  much

Comment: Another problem was meeted.Could you give some suggestion.Thank you very much.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848575/how-to-edit-table-data-with-interactive-event-in-matplotlib