# How to edit table data with interactive event in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, interactive

A table is created in a figure. Now I want to edit the table after double click at the cell, adding, deleting or revising the data in this cell. Just like the edit function in Excel. My python version is 3.64. Codes are following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Hide axes
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)

# Table from Ed Smith answer
clust_data = [[1,1,7]]
collabel=("col 1", "col 2", "col 3")
ax.table(cellText=clust_data,colLabels=collabel,loc='center')
plt.show()
```

Comment: It's definitely possible to edit the table; but it's nothing that is in any way built-in. So you need to program that functionality yourself. You need to register an event for double clicks, obtain the clicked artist, dynamically show an editable `matplotlib.widgets.TextBox` and then set the content of the table cell to that of the TextBox. I doubt this is something someone would just write for you; so try to implement this and then ask about any problem that occurs when doing so.

Comment: Yeah,the codes were found in this web.After many times searches, i still don't know the detail  about which controls or widget should be used

Comment: Recently, i find my expectations  are satisfied mostly by package wxpython  in python .But the interface plotted in matplotlib  isn't showed in wxpython.Are you familiar with it?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49893460/an-simple-interface-plotted-by-matplotlib-and-cartopy-isnt-showed-in-wxpython

Comment: There is now an answer available at [Editable table in Matplotlib: How to superimpose a TextBox widget on a table cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50932614/editable-table-in-matplotlib-how-to-superimpose-a-textbox-widget-on-a-table-cel/50934482#50934482)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you this is not easy to achieve using pure matplotlib functional.

You should consider looking at [qgrid](https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid) module, which provides interactive Excel-like table editing in Jupyter Notebook.

Then, if you want to change your graph accordingly, you will need to create some interaction with the table. [ipywidgets](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets) can really help you with that.

Comment: But i run the program in pycharm,not in Jupyter Notebook

Comment: Which module should be choosed

Comment: Actually, the type of work you are trying to perform is related to data analysis and manipulation. You should definitely try Jupyter Notebook for such tasks, because of it's interactivity and lots of useful widgets.

Comment: Wxpython may be the  better choice.