# Editable table in Matplotlib: How to superimpose a TextBox widget on a table cell?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm progressing towards creating an interactive table in Matplotlib. I want the user to be able to click on a data cell in the table so they can edit its value. Based on the advice of @ImportanceOfBeingErnest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49848575/1843329) I've registered a pick event handler for each cell of real data in the table. I can then detect which cell the user has clicked on. But I can't superimpose a `TextBox` object exactly over the picked cell so that to the user it looks like they're editing the cell they picked.

Dummy code to illustrate the issue:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.table import CustomCell
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox

def on_pick(event):

    if isinstance(event.artist, CustomCell):
        cell = event.artist
        # Doesn't work because cell.get_y() is negative:
        #text_box_axes = plt.axes([cell.get_x(), cell.get_y(), cell.get_width(), cell.get_height()])

        # This doesn't work either but at least you can see the TextBox on the figure!
        text_box_axes = plt.axes([cell.get_x(), -cell.get_y(), cell.get_width(), cell.get_height()])

        cell_text = cell.get_text().get_text()
        TextBox(text_box_axes, '', initial=cell_text)
        plt.draw()

column_labels = ('Length', 'Width', 'Height', 'Sold?')
row_labels = ['Ferrari', 'Porsche']
data = [[2.2, 1.6, 1.2, True],
        [2.1, 1.5, 1.4, False]]
table = plt.table(cellText=data, colLabels=column_labels, rowLabels=row_labels, cellLoc='center', loc='bottom')
text_box = None

celld = table.get_celld()
for key in celld.keys():
    # Each key is a tuple of the form (row, column).
    # Column headings are in row 0. Row headings are in column -1.
    # So the first item of data in the table is actually at (1, 0).
    if key[0] > 0 and key[1] > -1:
        cell = celld[key]
        cell.set_picker(True)

canvas = plt.gcf().canvas
canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', on_pick)
plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

But if I run this and then click on, say, the cell with `1.2` in it I see this:

[image]

So how do I get the bounds of the `TextBox` to exactly match the bounds of the cell that the user has clicked on?

It seems the axes for the textbox are relative to the whole figure rather than to the table itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cell's position is indeed given in axes coordinates, while the `TextBox`'s axes lives in figure coordinates. You may transform in between the two coordinate systems as

```
trans = figure.transFigure.inverted()
trans2 = ax.transAxes
bbox = cell.get_bbox().transformed(trans2 + trans)
text_box_axes.set_position(bbox.bounds)
```

Of course you then also need to make sure the cell text is updated according to the content of the `TextBox`, each time it is submitted.

The following would be a fully functional editable matplotlib table.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.table import CustomCell
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox

class EditableTable():
    def __init__(self, table):
        self.table = table
        self.ax = self.table.axes
        celld = table.get_celld()
        for key in celld.keys():
            if key[0] > 0 and key[1] > -1:
                cell = celld[key]
                cell.set_picker(True)
        self.canvas = self.table.get_figure().canvas
        self.cid = self.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.on_pick)
        self.tba = self.ax.figure.add_axes([0,0,.01,.01])
        self.tba.set_visible(False)
        self.tb = TextBox(self.tba, '', initial="")
        self.cid2 = self.tb.on_submit(self.on_submit)
        self.currentcell = celld[(1,0)]

    def on_pick(self, event):
        if isinstance(event.artist, CustomCell):
            # clear axes and delete textbox
            self.tba.clear()
            del self.tb
            # make textbox axes visible
            self.tba.set_visible(True)
            self.currentcell = event.artist
            # set position of textbox axes to the position of the current cell
            trans = self.ax.figure.transFigure.inverted()
            trans2 = self.ax.transAxes
            bbox = self.currentcell.get_bbox().transformed(trans2 + trans)
            self.tba.set_position(bbox.bounds)
            # create new Textbox with text of the current cell
            cell_text = self.currentcell.get_text().get_text()
            self.tb = TextBox(self.tba, '', initial=cell_text)
            self.cid2 = self.tb.on_submit(self.on_submit)

            self.canvas.draw()

    def on_submit(self, text):
        # write the text box' text back to the current cell
        self.currentcell.get_text().set_text(text)
        self.tba.set_visible(False)
        self.canvas.draw_idle()

column_labels = ('Length', 'Width', 'Height', 'Sold?')
row_labels = ['Ferrari', 'Porsche']
data = [[2.2, 1.6, 1.2, True],
        [2.1, 1.5, 1.4, False]]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
table = ax.table(cellText=data, colLabels=column_labels, rowLabels=row_labels, 
                 cellLoc='center', loc='bottom')

et = EditableTable(table)

ax.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

<strike>Note however that there is some bug sometimes preventing the cell to be correctly updated. I haven't found out the reason for this yet.</strike>
Note that in a previous version of this, a single TextBox instance was used. However this led to untraceable errors. Instead one would need to create a new instance each time a cell is clicked, as in the above updated version.

Comment: Thanks very much! For some inexplicable reason I'd completely overlooked the mention of figure-based coordinates at https://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html. I'll base my real code on your answer to explore this further. Yes, with the code you've given it works for the first cell I click on but subsequent cells throw `RuntimeError: Cannot get window extent w/o renderer` in matplotlib\text.py in `get_window_extent()`. I'm using Matplotlib 2.2.2.

Comment: It's not necessarily the second click, it can be the tenth click as well.. so [I'm a bit at loss](https://gitter.im/matplotlib/matplotlib?at=5b2954ec72b31d3691da4daa) on what's causing this currently.

Comment: Just want to check my understanding please... `trans = figure.transFigure.inverted()` converts from display -> figure coordinates. And `trans2 = ax.transAxes` converts from axes -> display coordinates. So adding them together in `cell.get_bbox().transformed(trans2 + trans)` converts the axes coords for the cell's bounds to figure coords in one go. And with `self.tba = self.ax.figure.add_axes([0,0,.01,.01])` you created a tiny initial `TextBox` which you then resize to the size of the cell that's clicked on using `self.tba.set_position(bbox.bounds)`. Neat!

Comment: Yes, that's all correct. It's very neat, indeed, except it's not working properly, due to the renderer problem :-(

Comment: Using your answer I was able to come up with my own solution (just posted). I'm not sure why yours doesn't work. Is it because you're trying to reuse the same `TextBox` object all the time? I appreciate that would be more efficient though.

Comment: Yep, creating a new TextBox (not a new axes though) seems to circumvent the problem. I updated the answer code.

Answer (score 0):

Using @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's very helpful answer I was able to adapt my original code to a working solution. Yes, I know it uses horrible globals, etc but at least it works!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.table import CustomCell
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox

def on_pick(event):

    if isinstance(event.artist, CustomCell):

        global text_box, current_cell, table
        if text_box is not None:
            plt.gcf().delaxes(text_box.ax)

        current_cell = event.artist
        table_axes = table.axes

        axes_to_display = table_axes.transAxes
        display_to_figure = table_axes.figure.transFigure.inverted()

        bbox = current_cell.get_bbox().transformed(axes_to_display + display_to_figure)
        text_box_axes = plt.axes(bbox.bounds)

        cell_text = current_cell.get_text().get_text()
        text_box = TextBox(text_box_axes, '', initial=cell_text)
        text_box.on_submit(update_table_cell)
        plt.draw()


def update_table_cell(new_value):

    global text_box, current_cell
    # Get rid of the textbox:
    plt.gcf().delaxes(text_box.ax)
    current_cell.get_text().set_text(new_value)
    text_box = None
    current_cell = None

    # TODO: Update the table data...
    plt.draw()


column_labels = ('Length', 'Width', 'Height', 'Sold?')
row_labels = ['Ferrari', 'Porsche']
data = [[2.2, 1.6, 1.2, True],
        [2.1, 1.5, 1.4, False]]
table = plt.table(cellText=data, colLabels=column_labels, rowLabels=row_labels, cellLoc='center', loc='bottom')
text_box = None
current_cell = None

celld = table.get_celld()
for key in celld.keys():
    # Each key is a tuple of the form (row, column).
    # Column headings are in row 0. Row headings are in column -1.
    # So the first item of data in the table is actually at (1, 0).
    if key[0] > 0 and key[1] > -1:
        cell = celld[key]
        cell.set_picker(True)

canvas = plt.gcf().canvas
canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', on_pick)
plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```