# Can I make the axis limit of the plot interactive in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let's say the following code draws a simple plot. Then I want to change the range of the X axis by change the last tick label of the X axis into an entry element, so I can just click the "10" then change it.

So basically build a entry element on top of the axis. Is it possible? I checked the matplotlib.widgets, it seems there is no such implementation yet.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataX = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
dataY = np.array([1193,1225,1125,1644,1255,13676,2007,2008,12359,1210])

ax = plt.subplot(111)

ax.plot(dataX, dataY, linewidth=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Matplotlib has a [`TextBox`](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/widgets/textbox.html) widget, so in principle this is possible. Now it can be made arbitrarily complicated or simple, depending on the requirement. Putting a static text box next to the axes is pretty easy. Having the textbox only become active upon clicking is [harder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50932614/editable-table-in-matplotlib-how-to-superimpose-a-textbox-widget-on-a-table-cel). Having the actual ticklabel become a textbox upon clicking is challenging. Maybe you can first comment on what you have tried already.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I could not find any direct solution. I noticed the TextBox but the problem is in my company the version of the matplotlib does not have this class...so I might have to ask them to update the package.

Comment: Otherwise I tried SpanSelector, tried to select the span I want. That's an indirect solution. Looks similiar but it's not quite I wanted. Will be probably the backup.

Comment: TextBox has been introduced in matplotlib 2.1. You can always try with a newer version just for yourself and if it works use it to convince someone to update the company version.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest hi! I tried to copy the source code of TextBox and test it as a local package....and it worked. I guess this gotta be my only and last resort since update of the lib in the organization is incredibly hard (I know what I mean)